# Web API parameter filtering

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This must be simple and I'm being incredibly dense but I can't find an example to help me figure it out.  I want to filter my list of `tblAsset` items by their `assessmentId` which is passed in through a parameter.  I'm able to get the parameter value ok, but I'm not sure how to write the query.

My model is built from an existing Database using the Model creation wizard.

Thanks for any help!

```
public IEnumerable<tblAsset> GettblAssets()
{
  NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
  var assessmentId = nvc["aid"];

  //limit the assets by assessmentId somehow and return
}
```

Comment: Not part of your question but you can also access the query string parameters like so (saves you having to use HttpUtility and manually parsing etc)... IEnumerable<tblAsset> GettblAssets([FromUri]int? assessmentId = null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `.Where` extension method on the `IQueryable<tblAsset>` instance returned by your database:

```
public IEnumerable<tblAsset> GettblAssets()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
    var assessmentId = nvc["aid"];

    // TODO: you might need to adjust the property names of your model accordingly
    // Also if the assessmentId property is an integer on your model type
    // you will need to parse the value you read from the request to an integer
    // using the int.Parse method
    return db.tblAsset.Where(a => a.assessmentId == assessmentId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked!  And yes, it was simple and I was being dense.